# Convention on model names in ruby on rails

Tags: coding-standards, ruby-on-rails, model, conventions

I was doing my ER diagram for a rails application I'm about to begin with and there I have an entity called `Class News` so I'd have a model `ClassNew` but I don't know if I will have problems in the future with the `New` part or what would be the right way to do this o how should I call the model? since the right thing would be `ClassNews` and the table should be `class_news`...

What's the best thing to do when working with `News` at the time of creating models for ActiveRecord in Ruby on Rails.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would the model be called "ClassNew" ?  "News" is an uncountable noun.  If RAILS doesn't already have "News" marked as uncountable, you can [change the rules](http://strugglingwithruby.blogspot.com/2010/03/rails-singularize-and-pluralize.html).

Comment: So, before running the migrations and generating the model, I could do `rails g model class_news title description` and `AR` will generate `ClassNews` model using `class_news` table and I'll be able to use without a problem if its marked as uncountable in `Rails`?

Comment: @Mr_Nizzle: If you are currently getting "ClassNew" from "class_news", instead of "ClassNews", then changing the rules to mark "News" as uncountable (like "fish") should fix that problem.

Comment: Thanks, ran the model generator with `ClassNews` and it generated the model `ClassNews` and the migration creates the table `class_news` and it works fine in the application like: `ClassNews.new` and `ClassNew.all`, seems like it won't mean any trouble.